# App login functionality issue

Tags: php, ios, authentication

Hi I am trying to create a simple login page for an application. The login will be done on the native app and not on a web. Currently there is no error when the simulator is run but at the same time there is no authentication being done. May I know as how do i implement authentication?

My code:

```
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender
{
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Agent_code=%@&Password=%@",[Agent_code text], [Password text]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test/login.php?"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"success",returnString);   
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

# Init the MySQL Connection



$username = "user";    

$dbname = "db";      

$password = "pass";         

$hostname = "localhost";        

$table = "table";


if (!($connectDB = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password))) 

die ('Failed to connect to MySQL Database Server - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error());



if (!mysql_select_db ($dbname))

die ('Connected to Server, but Failed to Connect to Database - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error());



# GETTING PARAMETERS

$Agent_code = $_GET['Agent_code'];

$Password = $_GET['Password'];



# Prepare the SELECT Query

$selectSQL = "SELECT Agent_code, Password FROM $table WHERE Agent_code = '$Agent_code' AND Password = '$Password'";



# Execute the SELECT Query

if (!($selectRes = mysql_query ($selectSQL))) {

echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();

} else {

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($selectRes);

  if (mysql_num_rows ($selectRes) == 1) {

    echo 'User and password found!';

  } else {

    echo 'Invalid Username or Password.';

  }

}

mysql_close($connectDB);

?>
```

Comment: You mean for **NSLog(@"success",returnString);** getting (null)...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. These could be the issues:

1. You haven't passed the Login Credentials to the API correctly.
2. Response Data hasn't been captured correctly.
3. Response hasn't been printed correctly. It should have been : `NSLog(@"success:%@",returnString);`

Pls try this Solution:

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)iSender {
    NSString *aContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Agent_code=%@&Password=%@",[Agent_code text], [Password text]];
    NSString *anURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test/login.php?%@", aContent];
    NSURL *anURL = [NSURL URLWithString:anURLString];

    NSError *anError = nil;
    NSURLResponse *anURLResponse;
    NSURLRequest *anURLRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:anURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    NSData *aResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:anURLRequest returningResponse:&anURLResponse error:&anError];

    NSString *aResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE = %@",aResponse);
}
```